# Syntax Error in program to sort patient names and temperatures

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am taking my first python course. I am to write a program that asks for how many patients to be entered, what their names are, their temperatures and sort the list. I need my program to then list the names with temperatures higher than 98.6 and  I am running into a syntax error just after the 98.6.

```
def getTempOver98_6(count, howMany, temp):
    # Reset count back to 0 to start at the top of the list
    count=0


    # while loop to determine letter grade
    while count < howMany:
        if temp[count] >= 98.6
        print(patientName, temp)
        count = count + 1

#END getTempOver98_6 FUNCTION
```

Comment: You're missing a colon, and some indentation. Please re-read whatever tutorial you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

def getTempOver98_6(howMany, temp):

```
# for loop removes the need to use the variable "count" 
# for loop compares all elements.
for count in range(howMany):
    if temp[count] >= 98.6:
        print(patientName, temp)
```

Comment: I think for loop will perform the task more conveniently and make the code easy.

Comment: hope u like my answer

Answer (score 0):

code with proper indentation

```
def getTempOver98_6(count, howMany, temp):
    # Reset count back to 0 to start at the top of the list
    count=0


    # while loop to determine letter grade
    while count < howMany:
        if temp[count] >= 98.6:
            print(patientName, temp)
        count = count + 1
```